Probability that the sum of two dice is even - Two different answers when using ordered and unordered method
First method is the probability using ordered pairs:
Even ordered pairs = Both die even + Both die odd = $|\{(2,2),(2,4),(2,6),(4,2),(4,4),(4,6),(6,2), (6,4), (6,6)\}| + |\{(1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(3,1),(3,3),(3,5),(5,1),(5,3),(5,5)\}| = 9+9 = 18$.
Total pairs = $6*6 = 36\implies$ Probability $=\dfrac{18}{36} = 0.5$
The second method is the probability using unique sets:
Unique sets where the sum is even: $|\{(2,2),(2,4),(2,6),(4,4),(4,6),(6,6)\}| + |\{(1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(3,3),(3,5),(5,5)\}| = 6+6 = 12$
Total unique sets $= 6+5+4+3+2+1 = 21 \implies$ Probability $\displaystyle=\frac{12}{21} = \frac{4}{7}$
How come the two methods give different probabilities? Thank you!

The unique sets approach is wrong.  When you enumerate specific elements, they must be equally likely, in order to make the approach valid.
With the unique sets approach, the [2:4] element is twice as likely as the [2:2] element (for example).  So the entire approach is invalid.
